# Ошибка Sphinx "no wordform separator found"

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch

Настриваю конфиг сфинкса и попробовал добавить файл wordforms.txt

Написал пример в wordforms.txt

эльфбар > Elf Bar

и получаю вот такую вот ошибку ( Нагуглить не смог... Прошу помощи

WARNING: index 'product': no wordform separator found (wordform='эльфбар > Elf Bar', file='/var/www/data/www/storage/sphinx/wordforms.txt'). IGNORED.